# "What if ... was" vs "what if ... were."

Tags: conditional-constructions

> What if she disliked my company but was/were too shy or embarrassed to
>   let me know?

I think this is a *unreal conditional sentence* ... but I'm not very sure because according to [Grammarly's blog](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/conditional-sentences-was-instead-of-were/), these type of sentences have "would" in them.

So I'm not sure whether I should use "was" or "were."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct answer is "was".

So, may your answer will look like:

> What if she disliked my company but was/were too shy or embarrassed to let me know?

Comment: Please can you add an explanation to this answer?